# Converting categorical character variable to numeric values in SAS

Tags: sas

My categorical variable has four levels - east, west, north, south. I want these levels to be 1, 2, 3, 4 (numeric form). How do I do that in SAS? Thank you!

Comment: If var='east' then new_var=1; if var='west' then new_var=2; ... ?

Comment: Please provide some more context around how you are going to use these values.  It may be that you just need to format them (look up `proc format`), which would avoid changing the value.  To qualify as a valid SO question, you should also post some code you've attempted

Answer (score 1):

There are reasons to prefer an INFORMAT over a FORMAT for creation of a numeric variable.

```
proc format cntlout= cntl;
    value $numvar
        east = 1
        west = 2
        north = 3
        south = 4
        other=.
    ;
    invalue numvar(upcase)
        EAST = 1
        WEST = 2
        NORTH = 3
        SOUTH = 4
        other=.
    ;
   run;
data _null_;
   do x='norTH' , 'South' , 'East' , 'west' , 'outer';
      length b 8;
      b = put(x,$numvar.);
      c = input(x,numvar.);
      put _all_;
      end;
   run;
```

Notice the different results and there is no conversion NOTE:

```
43         data _null_;
44            do x='norTH' , 'South' , 'East' , 'west' , 'outer';
45               length b 8;
46               b = put(x,$numvar.);
47               c = input(x,numvar.);
48               put _all_;
49               end;
50            run;

NOTE: Character values have been converted to numeric values at the places given by: (Line):(Column).
      46:11   
x=norTH b=. c=3 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
x=South b=. c=4 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
x=East b=. c=1 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
x=west b=2 c=2 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
x=outer b=. c=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest and the most appropriate way is to create format:

```
proc format;
    value $numvar
        east = 1
        west = 2
        north = 3
        south = 4
    ;
run;
```

In data step you just create new numeric variable:

```
/* data step code */
new_var = put(your_categorical_variable, $numvar.);
/* data step code */
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can easily change coding if necessary - make changes only in proc format and not in all data steps where you convert variables. It's impossible when you use hardcoding

```
if var='east' then new_var=1 ...
```

Comment: The question is vague, but I think they want a numeric variable. Above will make new_var character.

Comment: @Quentin, I agree. If exactly numeric is needed we can just add `LENGTH new_var 8;`   in data step before SET statement and new_var will be numeric. It causes warnings in log though. So the better decision is to `do new_var = input(put(your_categorical_variable, $numvar.), 1.);`

Comment: Or could make a user-generated informat rather than a format.